# CGAffineTransformScale and orientation change

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, cgaffinetransform

Good evening,

I scale down a UIView by using CGAffineTransformScale.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            gridContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.2, 0.2);
            gridContainerView.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // show UIView B
        }];
```

and scale it back to its original size:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    gridContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    gridContainerView.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // remove UIView B
}];
```

This works fine. The gridContainerView get scaled down to the center of the screen. However, if I change the devices orientation (to a.e. landscape) the center is somehow shifted to the bottom left. The transformation is not going to the center of the screen anymore once I change orientation. 
The only way to fix this is to release the gridContainerView and reallocate/init it. But unfortunately this is not an option for me at this point.

Any help is truly appreciated.